# Problem booting a Ubuntu install USB on a new Windows 11 ThinkPad

Tags: boot, usb, thinkpad

I have a new ThinkPad E16 Gen1 running Windows 11 (which is on the Ubuntu approved list). I created a bootable USB on this laptop but am unable to boot to it. I does show up in the BIOS but I am not able to select it. However I do not see it File Explorer.
As a side note if I put it into and older Acer running windows 10 it works as expected. I can boot to it and it does appear in File Manager.

I'd really appreciate any help, and will be more than happy to answer any questions.

Thanks
Edit: Part of problem resolved. I tried a different USB drive and now windows 11 does see it.
However so far I I have no idea how to boot to it and google hasn't helped yet. You can probably tell I'm not a windows guy by any stretch of the imagination.

Comment: New systems are UEFI/gpt only. Create flash drive in UEFI boot mode. Some tools to convert ISO to flash drive make it UEFI only or BIOS only even though ISO can be configured for both. Then from UEFI boot menu, you should have a UEFI:XXX boot entry where XXX is name or label of flash drive. You need at least Ubuntu 22.04.3 & may need 23.10 to have latest kernel & drivers for support of new systems.https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu#1-overview & https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/iso2usb & https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop#1-overview